# IntelliJ - Why Don't Dependencies Import with Maven Module?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I have an IntelliJ project 'myapp' that includes via pom.xml a module called 'common'.  The common module is designed to be a place where utility classes and common dependencies are specified like logging.

Here is pom.xml for my app:

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>test</groupId>
  <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <modules>
    <module>../common</module>
  </modules>
</project>
```

Here is the pom.xml for the common module:

```
<project>

  … other stuff

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.12</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

So I would expect to be able to use commons logging in myapp code without further steps.  However, this does not work.  Even if I manually add (and export) the common module as a dependency in myapp and mark the commons logging and log4j dependencies as exported in common, it still doesn't work.

Obviously, I can add the logging dependencies directly in myapp pom.xml, but I was hoping for a modular way to do this.  I am using IntelliJ 14.1.3 Ultimate.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

BTW: I tried to include some screen shots in this post, but apparently I don't have at least a '10 reputation' ;)